# Mac: Implementing NSUserNotification banner style window for Mac OSX 10.7

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications

I'm implementing NSUserNotification banner style window for Mac OSX 10.7. I've created my custom class to create a NSWindow with custom drawing to have look and feel like notification banner.

However, the banner window is displayed only if my application is active. If other application is active then it doesn't show up on the screen.

I've set the level of NSWindow to NSStatusWindowLevel.

Below code to display banner

```
-(void) showBanner
{
    [self orderFrontRegardless];
    [self setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel];
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: you have to use `NSFloatingWindowLevel` instead of `NSStatusWindowLevel` that will make your window visbible over others. But note that authentication window will still be above your this banner window.

Comment: for notifications you may think of using `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces` too to show your notification on all the workspaces.